# Sort a table after pulling from database

Tags: php, laravel, database

how can I sort a table after pulling the data from the database giving that the sort parameter is not a column in the database - basically, the sort parameter was just calculated on the fly using foreach after generating the data into a table from the database. For example: If I have a the following table after pulling from database: I want to be able to sort with the point column (in descending order), NOTE: the point column does not exist in the database, it was just determine on the fly as shown in the code below.

| points | name | no of posts | most likes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | ab | 5 | 69 |
| 4 | ac | 5 | 9 |
| 34 | ad | 1 | 99 |

```
@php
                    $winners = App\Models\Post::wherePostLive(1)->withCount('likes')->orderBy('user_id')->select('user_id')->distinct()->get()->take(15);
                @endphp
                <table class="table table-sm table-striped" id="caltbl">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Points
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                No of Articles
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Most Likes
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($winners as $keys => $winner)
                            @php
                                $likesTotals = App\Models\Post::wherePostLive(1)->withCount('likes')->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')->where('user_id', $winner->user->id)->get();
                                $totalLikes = 0; 
                                foreach($likesTotals as $key => $likesTotal) {
                                    $totalLikes += $likesTotal->likes_count;
                                }
                            @endphp
                        <tr>
                            @if($totalLikes > 6)
                            <td class="sortnr" style="width: 20%;">
                                {{ $totalLikes }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortnr" style="display: flex;">
                                <a style="display: contents;" class="author" href="{{ url('/profile/' . $winner->user->username) }}">
                                    @if (substr( $winner->user->avatar, 0, 4 ) === "http")
                                        <img class="avatar-sm img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ $winner->user->avatar }}" alt="{{ $winner->user->username }}">
                                    @else
                                        <img class="avatar-sm img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ url('/images/' . $winner->user->avatar) }}" alt="{{ $winner->user->username }}">
                                    @endif
                                    <div>
                                        {{ str_limit($winner->user->name, 22) }}
                                    </div>            
                                    @isset($winner->user->role)
                                    <div class="vbadge">
                                        <i class="icon-patch-check-fill verficon" style="vertical-align: inherit;" title="@lang('messages.new.verified')"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    @else
                                        <div class="vbadge">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-patch-minus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                                                <path d="m10.273 2.513-.921-.944.715-.698.622.637.89-.011a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 2.924 2.924l-.01.89.636.622a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 0 4.134l-.637.622.011.89a2.89 2.89 0 0 1-2.924 2.924l-.89-.01-.622.636a2.89 2.89 0 0 1-4.134 0l-.622-.637-.89.011a2.89 2.89 0 0 1-2.924-2.924l.01-.89-.636-.622a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 0-4.134l.637-.622-.011-.89a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 2.924-2.924l.89.01.622-.636a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 4.134 0l-.715.698a1.89 1.89 0 0 0-2.704 0l-.92.944-1.32-.016a1.89 1.89 0 0 0-1.911 1.912l.016 1.318-.944.921a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 0 2.704l.944.92-.016 1.32a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 1.912 1.911l1.318-.016.921.944a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 2.704 0l.92-.944 1.32.016a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 1.911-1.912l-.016-1.318.944-.921a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 0-2.704l-.944-.92.016-1.32a1.89 1.89 0 0 0-1.912-1.911l-1.318.016z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                    @endisset                
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortnr" style="width: 10%;">{{$keys + 1}}</td>
                            <td class="sortnr" style="width: 10%;">
                                {{$winner->likes_count}}
                            </td>
                            @endif
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Blending your processing logic with your printing logic has made your life harder than it needs to be.  Do all of your data preparation, then display the data after it is prepared.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have two methods to sort the table:

1. By eloquent model using Query Builder.
2. By using jQuery plugin, [Datatables](https://datatables.net/)

**[Method 1]**

In laravel data is sorted using eloquent query. So the better option is to do something like this, using *orderBy()*

```
$winners = App\Models\Post::wherePostLive(1)->withCount('likes')->orderBy('user_id')->select('user_id')->distinct()->orderBy('user_id', 'DESC')->get()->take(15);
```

For more information: [Laravel Query Builder orderBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#ordering)

**[Method 2]**

You can do sorting on client side using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin. Just import its CDN from the installation guide and there you'll also find a starter code.